# html5 localstorage binary pdf

Tags: android, html, pdf, cordova, local-storage

Is it possible to save and reopen a pdf file on localStorage?
I'm working with Cordoba 2.1 on Android project.
I need to download a pdf file from an URL and store it on a private folder, non accessible from users outside my App. Than I need to open this files.
If I download the files throw FileTransfer.download(), I don't know how to save the file on a private folder.
So I thought to save the file on localStorage using JQuery.get() function, put than I don't Know how to get back the file to open with my intent function.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news, there is no such thing like "a private folder".

You can get access files stored on smartphones. If you store a file inside the localstorage, what may work. The localstorage can be read from the device and your PDF can be extracted.

If you want to ensure that no one can read the file, you will have to write a plugin, which encrypts files.

**update**:
The question is, if the file must be secure, or just hard to read.

Comment: that's not 100% correct. On Android you can store files in a private folder that only your app can access.

Comment: And you can gain access to all files including the app, if you have access to the device and an USB-cable.

Comment: Sure? There are tool for not rootet iOS devices, that let explore all files at the device. I am pretty sure, that there are similar tools for not rootet Android devices. Now it depends, on how secure the content has to be. If it is ok to let them unencryptet the private folder is ok. May be the app has to check if the device is rootet and stops to work (if the content hast to be safe). Don't know if it is possible to check if its rootet or not.

Comment: Nope you need root. Since each app runs as a separate uid you can't get into their directory unless you are that uid or you are root. If you've got a user with a rooted phone then all bets are off. At least you are doing the best you can by segregating your files into your own app directory structure.

Comment: As I said, if I try to save the files on localStorage or with fileTransfer on "/data/data/{package name}" folder, the pdf reader don't read it. Anybody call tell me the right way to read it from one that way?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do when you are calling FileTransfer.download() on Android is to specify the private folder for your application. It is located at /data/data/{package name}. Where {package name} is the string that is stored as the *package* attribute of the *manifest* tag of your AndroidManifest.xml file.

The /data/data/{package name} directory is on your devices internal storage. Each Android application runs as it's own separate UNIX user id. Anything you put in the /data/data/{package name} directory is owned by that UNIX user id which protects it from other applications accessing it.

Comment: I tried but now the application I launch with the Intent can't open the file : "the path of the document is not valid".
       window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
        action: WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
        type: "application/pdf",
        url:  root + filename},
        function() {},function() {});